# Can I tell LaTeX to break a list?

Tags: lists

Quite often, I have lists with short items, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{braket}         % for \Set{}

\begin{document}
adsfasdf
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\Set{A}$
    \item $\Set{A, B}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C, D}$
    \item $\Set{B}$
    \item $\Set{C}$
\end{itemize}
test text tex
\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I know that I can get this with tables and three lists. But can I also achieve the same result simpler?

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{multicol}` and `\begin{multicols}{3} ... \end{multicols}` to wrap the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy method to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol,braket}         % for \Set{}

\newenvironment{multiitemize}[1][3]
   {\begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{itemize}}
   {\end{itemize}%
    \end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
adsfasdf
\begin{multiitemize}[2]
    \item $\Set{A}$
    \item $\Set{A, B}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C, D}$
    \item $\Set{B}$
    \item $\Set{C}$
\end{multiitemize}
test text tex
\begin{multiitemize}
    \item $\Set{A}$
    \item $\Set{A, B}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C}$
    \item $\Set{A, B, C, D}$
    \item $\Set{B}$
    \item $\Set{C}$
\end{multiitemize}
\end{document}
```

The environment `multiitemize` by default set itemize to three column. If you need customization, then you can give it as an argument.